# How to add a Line break when inserting a data into my table?

Tags: javascript

I am Using JavaScript Dom Manipulation to fetch data from api but whenever it enters a new data it will not show in the next line rather it shows in a same line.so here in in buildType function I am showing all my data from api and using DOM Manipulation the datas are shown in a table.

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Unive</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 5rem;
      }

      th,
      td {
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: left;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      }

      tr:hover {
        background-color: skyblue;
      }
      .search-bar {
        float: right;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 2px solid blue;
        width: 20%;
        border-radius: 25px;
      }
      input:focus {
        outline: 0;
      }
      h1 {
        text-align: center;
        color: blue;
      }
     
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <!-- <h1>Student Attendence Data</h1> -->
      <button type="submit" onclick="get_data()">Get Data</button>
      <button type="submit" onclick="pdfGenerator()">Get the PDF</button>
      <input type="date" id="start-date" onchange="datePicker()" />
      <input type="date" id="end-date" onchange="datePicker()" />
      <!-- <button type="submit" onclick="countStudent()">Get the Number</button> -->
      <!-- <button type="submit" onclick="searchData()">show</button> -->
      <input
        class="search-bar"
        id="search-field"
        type="search"
        placeholder="Search Here"
        onchange="searchData()"
      />

      <div id="canvas_div_pdf">
        <h1>Student Attendence Data</h1>
        <table id="table">
          <tr>
            <th>Registration Id</th>

            <th>Department</th>
            <th>Access time</th>
            <th>Access Date</th>

            <th>User Name</th>
            <th>Unit Id</th>
            <th>Card</th>
          </tr>

          <tr id="tr"></tr>
        </table>

        <div id="absent-present-data"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  


      // show data in a table

      function buildType(data) {
        var parsingData = JSON.parse(data);
        var table = document.getElementById("tr");

        for (var i = 0; i < parsingData?.log.length; i++) {
          var row = `
                                      <td>${parsingData.log[i]?.registration_id}</td>
                                      <td>${parsingData.log[i]?.department}</td>
                                      <td>${parsingData.log[i]?.access_time}</td>
                                      <td>${parsingData.log[i]?.access_date}</td>
                                      <td>${parsingData.log[i]?.user_name}</td>
                                      <td>${parsingData.log[i]?.unit_id}</td>
                                      <td>${parsingData.log[i]?.card}</td>
                                      </tr>

                                `;
          table.innerHTML += row;
        }
      }

    


  </body>
</html>
```

[so here i can see that the new id should go to the nextline but it wont happen in here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X5TZ.png)

Comment: Given that this is a UI issue, could you please edit the question to include the relevant HTML (copied from output after request) and CSS only, not JS. Then we can see an actual working example of the problem.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I updated please check